# How to pass nothing (empty value) to date time data type in RDL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I give empty value to date time data type in RDL. I am trying out the following but I am getting 01/01/00 to those row which doesn't have any data.

```
 =iif(Fields!D_date.Value is nothing,Nothing,Fields!D_date.Value)
```

Even if I use

```
 =iif(Fields!D_date.Value=0,Nothing,Fields!D_date.Value)
```

or

```
 =iif(Fields!D_date.Value="",Nothing,Fields!D_date.Value)
```

I am getting an error in my data rows.

I am passing '' into the stored procedure. If there is not data for that column.

This is the stored procedure I am using:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspDBLines]
    (@InLinesPerPage int)
AS
    DECLARE @TotalRows int
    DECLARE @Remainder int
    DECLARE @NumPages int
    DECLARE @NextPageRows int

    SET @TotalRows = 0

    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P_id) AS InvoiceRow,
        CusID, B_id, Inv_No, B_Desc, D_date, Qty, Size, Price, Amt
    INTO
        #tempInvoice
    FROM 
        Purchase_Details

    SET @TotalRows = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @TotalRows = 0
    BEGIN
        WHILE @TotalRows < @InLinesPerPage -- Add Blank Rows will generate blank invoice.
        BEGIN
            SET @TotalRows = @TotalRows + 1

            INSERT INTO #tempInvoice (InvoiceRow, CusID, B_id, Inv_No, B_Desc, D_date, Qty, Size, Price, Amt)
            VALUES (@TotalRows, '', '', 0, '', '', 0, '', 0, 0)
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Remainder = @TotalRows % @InLinesPerPage -- get remainder

        IF @Remainder != 0 
        BEGIN
            -- Get the current page increase by 1 because we have a remainder.
            SET @NumPages = @TotalRows / @InLinesPerPage + 1 
            SET @NextPageRows = @NumPages * @InLinesPerPage

            WHILE @TotalRows < @NextPageRows -- Add Blank Rows
            BEGIN
                SET @TotalRows = @TotalRows + 1

                INSERT INTO #tempInvoice (InvoiceRow, CusID, B_id, Inv_No, B_Desc, D_date, Qty, Size, Price, Amt)
                VALUES (@TotalRows, '', '', 0, '', '', 0, '', 0, 0)
            END
        END
    END

    SELECT * 
    FROM #tempInvoice 
    ORDER BY InvoiceRow ASC

    RETURN
```

Comment: have you tried `NULL` or empty string `""`

Comment: I got #Error for giving empty string "" inside RDL. I've tried NULL inside my expression, the intellisense doesn't allow to pass .

Comment: what do you do with the value? do you use it elsewhere? RDL should not have any problems with just `=Fields!D_date.Value`. put `NULL` inside the stored proc if empty

Comment: No, I am only using it for just displaying data. I tried changing inside SP. When I use NULL inside the expression  I got this error "Null is not declared, not supported, instead use System.DB.Null "

Comment: returning `NULL` on Stored Proc and `=Fields!D_date.Value` on RDL should work just fine. if it doesn't, check what the SP is returning

Comment: It is such a Stupid Question. Can you tell me how to check the sp chunk by chunk? I got no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

The table may very well have a date like `1/1/1900` filled in for all the invalid dates. So the report is just displaying what is there since they're not `NULL`.

So try this expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!D_date.Value <= CDate("1/1/1900"), Nothing, Fields!D_date.Value)
```

If they really are `NULL` use this:

```
    =IIf(Fields!D_date.Value = Nothing, Nothing, Fields!D_date.Value)
```

SSRS doesn't use the `is` operator to compare with `Nothing`.